# Attribute-based routing, arguments with different name to variable - aspnetcore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger, nswag

I need to do this

```
[Route("/api/highfive/{person_name}")]
public IActionResult HighFive(string personName){
   //do stuff
}
```

Is there a way to map variable personName to what is supplied as person_name from the route?

The two below options work -as long as there is a match between route argument and variable name (which makes sense).

```
[Route("/api/highfive/{person_name}")]
public IActionResult HighFive(string person_name){
   //do stuff
}

[Route("/api/highfive/{personName}")]
public IActionResult HighFive(string personName){
   //do stuff
}
```

> But why do you want this??

- Swagger generates documentation that has to match that of a previous API, this is replacing - and it uses the variable names from route to generate documentation.
- using person_name as a variable name is against our naming conventions
- Yes it is kind of silly - but if there is an easy fix I am not aware of, that would be awesome.

Comment: check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [binding source attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.2#sources) allow for configuration of the name used for model-binding. In your example, you're getting the value from the route, which means you can use the `FromRoute` attribute on the parameter:

```
[FromRoute(Name="person_name")] string personName
```